# Combing 3 Arrays using Zip to get a Tuple of three

Tags: arrays, scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I have a Array like below

```
val a1 = Array("a","b","c")
var a2= Array("Apple","Box","Cat")
var a3= Array("Angel","Ball","Count")
```

I can use zip function to make a tuple of two. But how can I get a result like below?

```
Array(("a","Apple","Angel"),("b","Box","Ball"),("c","Cat","Count"),)
```

Comment: `(a1, a2, a3).zipped.toArray`

Comment: `zipped` is deprecated in Scala 2.13. in 2.13, `a1.lazyZip(a2).lazyZip(a3).toArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over indices and `map`:

```
val result = a1.indices.map(index => (a1(index), a2(index), a3(index)))
```

That will create a `Vector`. If you want an `Array`, simply: `result.toArray`.

Comment: Unlike .zipped, this solution fails if a1 is longer than a2 or a3.